# binomial probability, two variable

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

im confused about what this problem is asking:
A die is cast 5 times, event X1 is a success for {1,2,3} and X2 is success for {4,5}.  find:
$$P(X_1=2,X_2=1)$$
is this asking for the probabilities of X1 and X2?

this is what i have:
$$P(X_1)= {{5}\choose{2}}(1/2)^2(1/2)^3=5/16 $$
$$P(X_2)= {{5}\choose{1}}(1/3)^1(2/3)^4=80/243 $$
$$P(X_1=2,X_2=1)=\frac{5}{16}\frac{80}{24}=\frac{25}{243}$$

Comment: This is a little confusing.  As it stands, $X_1$ can't be $2$.  $X_1$ is either "success" or "fail".  I assume you are also using $X_1$ to denote the number of successes on five independent trials but I wouldn't denote that with the same variable name.

Comment: Assuming I have understood the question properly, then your computation is incorrect as it assumes independence where, in fact, $X_1,X_2$ are mutually exclusive.

Comment: both X1 and X2 can be any value from 0-5.  X1=2 is two successes out of the five rolls, or two of the five rolls were {1,2,3}

Comment: As I say, you have two different definitions of each $X_i$, that's a bad idea.  But, yes, this is what I figured you meant.  As I said, your computation is then incorrect because you falsely assume independence.

Comment: Well, they would be independent *if* measured on two *different* sequences of five rolls.  However, not so if $X_1, X_2$ are measured on the *same* five rolls.  The OP should clarify which is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each trial you have three mutually exclusive and exhaustive events. $$E_1=\{1,2,3\}, E_2=\{4,5\}, E_3=\{6\}$$

Let $p_1,p_2,p_3$ be the respective probabilities for these events on any particular trial.

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be the respective counts of occurrences of these events in five trials.

These random variables will follow a multinomial distribution; which is an extension of a binomial distribution.

$$\mathsf P(X_1{=}x,X_2{=}y, X_3{=}(5-x-y)) ~=~ \dfrac{5!}{x!\,y!\,(5-x-y)!}\; p_1^{\raise{0.5ex}x}\,p_2^y\,p_3^{5-x-y}$$

We turn it back over to you.

Comment: thanks, thats the correct way, i was just confused by the wording of the question.